# Populate GoogleMap with XML

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I created a custom XML structure for my Map Points.  The structure looks like the code below.  I'm wanting to read the points in and put them on the map accordingly with a popup window when clicked and a specific marker icon.  I would appreciate any help.

MapPoints.xml

```
<MapPoints>
<MapPoint PointID="1">
    <LocationName></LocationName>
    <LocationAddress></LocationAddress>
    <LocationURL></LocationURL>
    <LocationExt></LocationExt>
    <LocationFax></LocationFax>
    <LocationLat></LocationLat>
    <LocationLong></LocationLong>
    <LocationMarker></LocationMarker>
</MapPoint>
<MapPoint PointID="2">
    <LocationName></LocationName>
    <LocationAddress></LocationAddress>
    <LocationURL></LocationURL>
    <LocationExt></LocationExt>
    <LocationFax></LocationFax>
    <LocationLat></LocationLat>
    <LocationLong></LocationLong>
    <LocationMarker></LocationMarker>
</MapPoint>
<MapPoint PointID="3">
    <LocationName></LocationName>
    <LocationAddress></LocationAddress>
    <LocationURL></LocationURL>
    <LocationExt></LocationExt>
    <LocationFax></LocationFax>
    <LocationLat></LocationLat>
    <LocationLong></LocationLong>
    <LocationMarker></LocationMarker>
</MapPoint>
<MapPoint PointID="4">
    <LocationName></LocationName>
    <LocationAddress></LocationAddress>
    <LocationURL></LocationURL>
    <LocationExt></LocationExt>
    <LocationFax></LocationFax>
    <LocationLat></LocationLat>
    <LocationLong></LocationLong>
    <LocationMarker></LocationMarker>
</MapPoint>
</MapPoints>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples that parse xml in the "Mike Williams Google Maps API v2 tutorial" format using attributes, [here is one](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html).

To use your "custom" format, you will need to replace this line (to look for "MapPoint" rather than "marker"):

```
var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
```

and these lines:

```
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
      var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
      // create the marker
      var marker = createMarker(point,label,html);
```

With code that parses the element content out of your xml.

To get the element content you will need to do something like:

```
var lat = parseFloat(nodeValue(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("LocationLat")[0]));
```

Where nodeValue (borrowed from geoxml3) is:

```
//nodeValue: Extract the text value of a DOM node, with leading and trailing whitespace trimmed
geoXML3.nodeValue = function(node) {
  var retStr="";
  if (!node) {
    return '';
  }
   if(node.nodeType==3||node.nodeType==4||node.nodeType==2){
      retStr+=node.nodeValue;
   }else if(node.nodeType==1||node.nodeType==9||node.nodeType==11){
      for(var i=0;i<node.childNodes.length;++i){
         retStr+=arguments.callee(node.childNodes[i]);
      }
   }
   return retStr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jquery](http://jquery.org/).  In the head of your html doc, put this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

Now use a jQuery ajax call to the local XML file.

```
        //pulls in the xml
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
            url: "MapPoints.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('MapPoint').each(function(){
                    var lat = $.trim(this.LocationLat);
                    var lng = $.trim(this.LocationLng);

                    //use the same method to extract your other data
                    var mappoint = new google.maps.LatLng(lng,lat);

                    //now create the marker and set it to your map
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position:mappoint,
                     map:map,
                     title:'Your Marker Title',
                     icon:null
                    });

                });

            }
            });
```